# Sort a list alphabetically excluding a letter

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of objects each with a name.  I'm trying to sort the list in alphabetical order (which is easily accomplished) but then I want any item beginning with the letter D to be sorted following the alphabetically sorted list. so given the items:

```
(Apple, Door, Banana, Doorknob, Gorilla, Hammer)
```

I would like to sort this as :

```
(Apple, Banana, Gorilla, Hammer, Door, Doorknob)
```

I'm sure I could handle this using brute force, but I was hoping there was a way to do it with linq with `OrderBy().ThenBy()`  but it looks like thats more for sorting on 2 different properties. Is what im trying to do possible with linq, or do I just have to do it the old fashioned way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use any expression that returns a sortable value as a sort order; it doesn't have to be a property.  To put all objects whose name starts with "D" at the end of the list just use:

```
.OrderBy(o => o.Name.StartsWith("D") ? 1 : 0)
.ThenBy(o => o.Name)
```

Comment: You could make this shorter by removing the ternary operator. "false" is sorted before "true".

Comment: @gunr2171 True, but since that's not intuitive I'd rather be explicit than have to remember what order they get sorted in.